# Horizontal ticker with images 0 speed onClick js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/scriv/yjs21goz/

I have made this horizontal ticker but 
I need it to stop when user clicks on any of the images until user clicks again and along with that enlarge the image that was clicked

I have tried to add this piece of code that is in comments but it completely ruins the code

```
    $(function(){
    var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
    var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
    scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
    var curX = 0;
    scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('left', curX);
        curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
    });
    var fullW = curX / 2;
    var viewportW = scroller.width();

    // Scrolling speed management
    var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:2};
    var $controller = $(controller);
    var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
    {
        if (duration === undefined)
            duration = 600;
        $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
    };

    // Pause on hover
    scroller.hover(function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(0);
    }, function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });

    // Pause and enlarge onClick

  //  scroller.onClick(function(){
    //  tweenToNewSpeed(0);
   // }, function(){
     //   tweenToNewSpeed(controller,fullSpeed);
   // }); 

    // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
    var doScroll = function()
    {
        var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
        var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
        if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
            newX -= fullW;
        scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
    };
    setInterval(doScroll, 20);
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
});
```

Edit enlarge function(attempt):

```
function enlarge() {
 var pic = document.getElementById("#scroller li");
  if(img.style.width == "50px") {
      img.style.width = "200px";
  } else {
      img.style.width = "50px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you using `setInterval()` look for the use of `clearInterval()`.

Comment: @reporter I didn't quite catch you there. You mean replace     setInterval() with clearInterval() ?

Comment: No, If you would read the documentation of clearInterval you will find out that it breaks the effect of setInterval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clearInterval`

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1eupzh9/)</kbd>

Set your `setInterval` in a `variable`

```
var myInterval = setInterval(doScroll, 20);
```

Then add click `event` to toggle play/pause ticker:

```
  $('.innerScrollArea ul li').click(function(){

    if (!myInterval) {
      myInterval = setInterval(doScroll, 20); // play again!
    } else {
      clearInterval(myInterval); // pause!
      myInterval = null;
    }

  });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what part of my code I should replace? or paste the jsFiddle with the replacement?

Comment: @Scriv You already have it, it's just in my answer, check for button

Comment: Thank you but I can't mark your answer as the right one since there is the 2nd part of enlarging the images onClick. I am working on it so you should get your cookie pretty soon my friend :)